# Angular shared assets within multiple applications

Tags: angular, sass, angular-library

I am working on multiple small apps, which will share common and shared modules, and assets.

The part about how to create project structure was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61254557/1351452

My project folders structure is as follow:
-root
--projects
---app1
---app2
---library

1. I want to share assets (images and fonts) between apps and library (for example I have header component with logo)
2. I want to have one place for all the css (SCSS). Some compoents from shared library have also SCSS, but I think I should keep it separate (because within component, css code is added to index file  tag)
3. Where should I keep that shared-assets folder, how to configure it for build and how to access from each app (import scss and get images and fonts).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update: Octombre-2021 Angular 12.2.0**

you must add [object assets](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration):

```
{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "assets",
  "output": "assets"
}
```

project structure:

```
root
├── assets
│   ├── logo.png
│   └── ...
└── projects
    ├── app1
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── assets
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └── ...
    └── app2
        ├── src
        │   ├── assets
        │   └── ...
        └── ...
```

angular.json:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "app1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "projects/app1/src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "assets",
                "output": "assets"
              }
            ],
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "projects/app2/src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "assets",
                "output": "assets"
              }
            ],
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Original**

Put assets in root folder:
`root/assets/`

and change the path to assets in `angular.json`

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "app1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              //  change this
              // "projects/app1/src/assets",
              "assets",
            ],
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              //  change this
              // "projects/app2/src/assets",
              "assets",
            ],
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - Angular tells me `The assets asset path must start with the project source root.`

Comment: This approach doesn't work. This answer worked for us. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58739760/10941

Comment: This approach works when `assets` folder path is the path you want to include like `projects/app2/src/assets` as `input` value.

Comment: I had to do:
`"assets": ["projects/<name>/src/assets",{"glob": "**/*", "input": "assets/", "output": "assets/"}]`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve pretty much the same thing. However, I do not build my library. I just link to the library.module and use the components like that.

**And now, for the shared assets:**

In `angular.json`, I added the library's .scss to the app's build options, so it looked like this:

```
"styles": [
  "projects/library/src/styles.scss",
  "projects/app1/src/styles.scss"
],
```

I did not add the library's asset folder to the project's asset section because according to CLI "tHaT DoEsN't WoRk" (`The assets asset path must start with the project source root.`)

Now what?! I realised the font files I declared in my library's style.scss got copied. This lead me to this thought: What happens, if I also reference my assets in that file? So I put this in the `project/library/src/styles.scss`:

```
// fixes for library assets (they're not included if not listed here)
.its-2020-and-this-still-doesnt-work-out-of-the-box {
  background-image: url('assets/my-shared-logo.svg');
}
```

Then I was able to reference these assets from within my library's components like this:

```
<!-- library assets must be loaded from root level -->
<img src="my-shared-logo.svg" alt="" />
```